# Array that outputs cells in a column AFTER a certain point

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array formula that outputs all values in a range that are not 0 or text.

This range is mainly numbers and one cell of text which is the descriptive header.

However, I need the array to start outputting only when it detects the text that is present in the column (This could be in cell AA4 or could be AA40, it is different each time) and only output the numbers AFTER this point.

For example, given the following in a column:

```
525
0
22
464
Type
233
0
453
665
```

Only the numbers 233, 453, 665 should be output by the array.

At the moment it just looks at the range and outputs anything that isn't a 0 or text, regardless of it being above or below the header text. So 525,22,464,233,453,665 would all be output at the moment.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($AA$4:$AA$978, SMALL(IF($AA$4:$AA$978<>0, ROW($AA$4:$AA$978)-MIN(ROW($AA$4:$AA$978))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")
```

What do I need to alter/add to perform this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *value_if_false* clause within the `IF` statement is not strictly necessary. Also, `ROWS` is more rigorous than `ROW` for `SMALL`'s *k* parameter (see [here](https://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/) for an explanation as to why).

You need:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($AA$4:$AA$978,SMALL(IF($AA$4:$AA$978<>0,IF(ROW($AA$4:$AA$978)-MIN(ROW($AA$4:$AA$978))+1>MATCH("Type",$AA$4:$AA$978,0),ROW($AA$4:$AA$978)-MIN(ROW($AA$4:$AA$978))+1)),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")`

Unless you're actually using an Excel Table, I'd probably amend some of the references in the above so as to make it more efficient, viz:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($AA:$AA,SMALL(IF($AA$4:$AA$978<>0,IF(ROW($AA$4:$AA$978)>MATCH("Type",$AA:$AA,0),ROW($AA$4:$AA$978))),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")`

With a range of just under a thousand cells, you're probably fine to continue to use an `IFERROR` set-up, though note that, for larger ranges, this can be extremely inefficient - an explanation and alternative set-up is given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values).

Regards

Comment: Works as intended. However, I am missing the last row of data. Given the example above, 665 would be missing unless I set all `$AA$978` to `$AA$979`, then it would appear. However row 979 is blank and 665 is in row 978. Why would this occur?

Comment: I'm afraid your comment doesn't make much sense. Are you using the precise version of the formula as I posted it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `Array Formula` which requires a special key stroke `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` instead of Enter alone.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX($AA$4:$AA$978,MATCH(TRUE,ISTEXT($AA$4:$AA$978),0)+1):$AA$978,SMALL(IF(INDEX($AA$4:$AA$978,MATCH(TRUE,ISTEXT($AA$4:$AA$978),0)+1):$AA$978<>0,ROW(INDEX($AA$4:$AA$978,MATCH(TRUE,ISTEXT($AA$4:$AA$978),0)+1):$AA$978)-ROW(INDEX($AA$4:$AA$978,MATCH(TRUE,ISTEXT($AA$4:$AA$978),0)+1))+1),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")
```

and copy it down.

Comment: If you're committing that with CSE then the additional, coercing INDEX functions are superfluous.

Comment: Good catch. I removed the first one but forgot to remove the later occurrences. :)