# Array not outputting last cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Following on from this question:
[Array that outputs cells in a column AFTER a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628913/array-that-outputs-cells-in-a-column-after-a-certain-point)

I have made a simplified example to test the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11))>MATCH("WORD",$A$1:$A$11,0),ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11))),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")
```

Here is my sample data In column A, and array formula in column B (Entered with ctrl + shift + enter)
:

[image: example]

The array is outputting the cells that are found after the WORD. However, you can see that 10 is not being displayed by the array.
I will display if I change all ranges in the formula to `A1:A12`, but this is not correct surely.

What is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `>MATCH` to `>=MATCH` ?

Comment: The array formula you've provided just gives me "6" in every cell...

Comment: Same. I don't get the results you show in screenshot.

Comment: Where's the +1 gone from the end of ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11)) which was part of my solution of your original question?

Comment: It gave the text/word as the first output from the array

Comment: Only if you have the +1 with ONE of the ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11)) constructions. You require it (as per my original solution) with BOTH.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add 1 to the row output from the small, 11 - 1 = 10, So then you need to deal with the > Match by using >= MATCH:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF(ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11))>=MATCH("WORD",$A$1:$A$11,0),ROW($A$1:$A$11)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$11))+1),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Note Scott also added +1, to avoid matching the 0th match, "WORD". Nice solution.

Comment: @Demo. But you appear to have miscopied my orginal formula for some reason.

Comment: @XORLX sorry I did not follow the link, I assumed that this was a new question.  It is up to you, I can close this as duplicate and delete my answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner No worries. Let's wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Remember I can only delete it if it has not been marked as correct.  @XORLX  I appreciate your understanding.